# Error 1452 Foreign Key Fails

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-sql, mysql-error-1452

I am getting a 1452 error from MySQL. Here is the SQL I used to INSERT

```
INSERT INTO `Quote` (`QTE_id`, `USR_id`, `QTE_total`, `QTE_desc`, `QTE_dateCreated`, `QTE_dateModified`,`QTE_name`, `QTE_status`)
```

VALUES
    (39, 2, NULL, 'desc', '2013-11-19 00:00:00', '2013-11-19 11:22:49', 'test', 'Active');

```
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`dbNAME`.`Quote`, CONSTRAINT `USR_id1` FOREIGN KEY (`USR_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`USR_id`))
```

I am positive that the `USR_id` I am trying to put into the Quote table exists. Any ideas? A lot of the other questions on Stack Overflow did not answer my question.

Here is the Create syntax for the following tables I am trying to insert and relate (generated from Workbench):

```
CREATE TABLE `Quote` (
 `QTE_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `USR_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `QTE_total` decimal(7,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `QTE_desc` text,
  `QTE_dateCreated` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `QTE_dateModified` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `QTE_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `QTE_status` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`QTE_id`),
   KEY `USR_id1` (`USR_id`),
   CONSTRAINT `USR_id1` FOREIGN KEY (`USR_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`USR_id`)
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=39 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

And the User Table:

```
CREATE TABLE `Users` (
 `USR_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `MGR_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' 
  `REP_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `USR_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `USR_login` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `USR_dateModified` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `USR_dateCreated` datetime NOT NULL,
  `USR_role` enum('Salesperson','Manager') DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`USR_id`,`MGR_id`,`REP_id`),
  KEY `MGR_id_idx` (`MGR_id`),
  KEY `REP_id_idx` (`REP_id`),
  KEY `USR_login` (`USR_login`),
  CONSTRAINT `MGR_id` FOREIGN KEY (`MGR_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`USR_id`) ON DELETE NO     ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `REP_id` FOREIGN KEY (`REP_id`) REFERENCES `representative` (`REP_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to do a few small changes (change the `users` to `Users`, add a ',' at the end of line that defines `MGR_id`, remove the constraint for `REP_id`) to make the two CREATEs to work.

Here are the exact CREATEs:

```
CREATE TABLE `Users` (
 `USR_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `MGR_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `REP_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `USR_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `USR_login` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `USR_dateModified` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `USR_dateCreated` datetime NOT NULL,
  `USR_role` enum('Salesperson','Manager') DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`USR_id`,`MGR_id`,`REP_id`),
  KEY `MGR_id_idx` (`MGR_id`),
  KEY `REP_id_idx` (`REP_id`),
  KEY `USR_login` (`USR_login`),
  CONSTRAINT `MGR_id` FOREIGN KEY (`MGR_id`) REFERENCES `Users` (`USR_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE `Quote` (
 `QTE_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `USR_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `QTE_total` decimal(7,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `QTE_desc` text,
  `QTE_dateCreated` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `QTE_dateModified` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE     CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `QTE_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `QTE_status` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`QTE_id`),
   KEY `USR_id1` (`USR_id`),
   CONSTRAINT `USR_id1` FOREIGN KEY (`USR_id`) REFERENCES `Users` (`USR_id`)
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=39 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

With that in place the following two INSERTs worked:

```
mysql> INSERT INTO `Users` (`USR_id`, `MGR_id`) VALUES(2, 2);
Query OK, 1 row affected, 4 warnings (0.22 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `Quote` (`QTE_id`, `USR_id`, `QTE_total`, `QTE_desc`, `QTE_dateCreated`, `QTE_dateModified`,`QTE_name`, `QTE_status`) VALUES (39, 2, NULL, 'desc', '2013-11-19 00:00:00', '2013-11-19 11:22:49', 'test', 'Active');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.22 sec)
```

I hope this helps.